# How to calculate Trace function for a point on an elliptic curve

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, finite-field

I encountered trouble with calculating **Tr** (trace function) for points on an elliptic curve in polynomial basis ( $GF(2^m), m = 431$). Maybe there are any assumptions that can simplify and allow efficiently to calculate **Tr** operation?
I used the [Seroussi](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-94R1.html) approach to decompress points but it seems like I need some basic knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $F_q$, and let $\#E(F_q ) = q +1−t$. In this case, $t$ is called the trace of $E$.

Also, $\#E(F_{q^n} ) = q^n + 1 − V_n$ for all $n ≥ 2$, where $\{V_n\}$ is the sequence defined recursively by $$V_0 = 2, V_1 = t,\text{ and }V_n = V_1V_{n−1}−qV_{n−2}$$ for $n ≥ 2$. In your question it's enough to compute $V_{431}$.

For more details, see [Guide to Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387952734).

Comment: The Trace of Frobenius (t) is not the same as the Trace function (Tr) operating on curve points.

Answer (score 2):

For a point $p = (x, y)$ on a curve $E(F_{q^k})$, where $q$ is prime and $k$ is the *embedding degree* of $E$, the *trace map* is defined by
$$
        \mathbf{Tr}(p) = \sum_{i=0}^{k - 1}(x^{q^i}, y^{q^i}).
$$

I am not sure how that maps to curves with a polynomial basis, though.

There is a very good discussion of the r-torsion and the trace map in section 4.1 of Craig Costello's book *Pairings for Beginners*, which is very similar to section 2.3.1 of his [PhD thesis](http://www.craigcostello.com.au/wp-content/uploads/CraigCostelloThesis.pdf).